# Storing Polygons in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When a user zooms into my map, I send the current bounding box to get the polygons from the database and set them in localStorage. They are transferred as JSON so something like `[{"polygons":{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[...]]` (with actual coordinates of course).

```
bounds = getBounds();
$.ajax({
    url: '/getPolygons',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(bounds),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        polyArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('polygons')) || [];
        polygons = data;
        polyArray.push(polygons);
        localStorage.setItem('polygons', JSON.stringify(polyArray));
    }
});
```

As the user further explores (pan, zoom) the map, the polygons keep on adding to the same localStorage key. My question is, **how do I load these polygons now that they are in the localStorage?** I want to reduce the number of requests sent to the database. If certain polygons have already loaded on the map, I do not want to request for those polygons again from the database.

I am able to set and get the polygons from localStorage, but the problem I have is with logic, which is as follows. This is the complete function.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('polygons')) {
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('polygons'));
        map.data.addGeoJson(data['polygons']);
    } else {
        bounds = getBounds();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getPolygons',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(bounds),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                addPolygons(data);
                polyArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('polygons')) || [];
                polygons = data;
                polyArray.push(polygons);
                localStorage.setItem('polygons', JSON.stringify(polyArray));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This the `addPolygons` function as used above:

```
function addPolygons(json) {
    data = json;

    if (typeof polygons !== 'undefined') {
        map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
            map.data.remove(feature);
        });
    }

    polygons = map.data.addGeoJson(data['polygons']);   
}
```

The bounding box is defined as follows:

```
function getBounds() {
    var boundsNE = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
    var boundsSW = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
    var ne = [ boundsNE.lng(), boundsNE.lat() ];
    var nw = [ boundsSW.lng(), boundsNE.lat() ];
    var sw = [ boundsSW.lng(), boundsSW.lat() ];
    var se = [ boundsNE.lng(), boundsSW.lat() ];
    var ne = [ boundsNE.lng(), boundsNE.lat() ];
    var boundsArray = [ ne, nw, sw, se, ne ];
    return boundsArray;
}
```

---

**Edit**: It worked using `map.data.addGeoJson(data['polygons']);` (see 3rd line in the IF statement I have setup). But now when I start panning the map, I don't see new polygons being requested from the database (the ones that don't exist on the map).

**Edit v2**: One thing I am experimenting with is tracking the change in map center. If the map center changes by X number of value, then request new polygons. Hope to update with answer if I can get this working.

**Edit v3**: This is what `polyArray` looks like after second fetch. Initial fetch is empty. 
`[Object]
   0: Object
    polygons: Object
      features: Array[209]
      type: "FeatureCollection"
       __proto__: Object
       __proto__: Object
   1: Object
    polygons: Object
      features: Array[205]
      type: "FeatureCollection"
       __proto__: Object
         __proto__: Object
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]`

Comment: As requested in the (now deleted) previous version of this question: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are trying to solve. I don't seem to have any trouble storing and retrieving polygons (displayed on a map) from localStorage (in my own JSON format).

Comment: Hi @geocodezip -- yes now I am able to also store and retrieve polygons but only for the initial viewport. When the bounds change, new polygons that don't exist in `localStorage` do not get requested from the database. I am trying to provide an example through a JSFiddle. I just don't have access to dev server right now.

Comment: My suspicion is that you need to be smarter about how you merge the new polygons into your `polyArray`.  What does polyArray look like after the second fetch?

Comment: Initially, it is empty (`[]`). After second fetch, it's an object. I've added the `console.log` results in my question above. So the number of features in the array change depending on what makes into the viewport.

Comment: But you only want update the array of features, you have an array of feature collections.  You can probably make it work this way, but I don't think it will work with your current code.  Are you doing any checking to prevent duplicate polygons?

Comment: @geocodezip No preventing of duplicate polygons. How would I be able to detect that? Do polygons need to be assigned an ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function ()` a `bounds_changed` function instead. Suggestion based on Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents):

> the Maps API fires these latter events independently, getBounds() may
>   not report useful results until after the viewport has authoritatively
>   changed. If you wish to getBounds() after such an event, be sure to
>   listen to the bounds_changed event instead.

"latter" events means the `zoom_changed` or `center_changed` which may not be the most effective approach.

**EDITED SNIPPET** (with a second of timeout):

```js
var timeout;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('polygons')) {
        ...
      } else {
        bounds = getBounds();
        ...
      }
    });
  },
  1000);
```

Comment: But the `bounds_changed` event continues to fire as you pan the map. This means that my `getBounds()` function (see above) will continue to keep sending bounding box coordinates until the panning stops. This slows down the map.

Comment: You have to set timeout for that. I will update my answer.

Comment: So ideally because of this setback of `bounds_changed` your previous logic is better, but considering your specific use-case I think this could be an effective workaround.